# how to export into csv in mongodb using file option

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am exporting collection to CSV format in MongoDB. while exporting into CSV I have put all the fieldname into a text file. but, it is not exporting the data in the collection, only header are exported.
WHERE IS THE PROBLEM?

```
mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --type=csv --fieldFile c:/data.txt --out /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

I have saved fieldname in data.txt as

```
email XOXA
name XOXA
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to export field names to a separate file if you are not using really old mongo version.

Try this

```
mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --type=csv -f email,name --out /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

Make sure that you don't have spaces between field names

```
-f email, name // this is wrong
```

If this command works, then you have problem with your fieldFile.